# Model validation issues on foreign key object references

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm starting checking out asp.net 6 / mvc / entity framework application and am running into trouble with just a basic test application. My foreign key object (not the ID itself) is making my ModelState.Isvalid false on the Create of a Scaffolded Controller.

Changed a few field names for simplicity, but it is basically this with a few extra strings in the model - picture a user with a required department:

```
[Column("deptId")]
public int DeptId { get; set; } // <== ValidationState = Valid

[ForeignKey("DeptId")]
[InverseProperty("Users")]
public virtual Dept dept { get; set; } = null!; // <== ValidationState = InValid
```

Model was created with a Scaffold-DbContext.

I can do a "ModelState.Remove("Dept")" and everything passes.

I can recreate exactly in asp.net 3.1 and it has no issues. The virtual Dept object isn't checked but it is in asp.net 6. Is this now expected? Is there a fix or a better way than applying a ModelState.Remove for every foreign key Object on every create? Am I missing something new that is telling that field to be validated?

Comment: Instead of using your DB models in views you should research the usage of ViewModels. This (and more) is the exact reason for using view models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set the property as follow:

```
public virtual Dept? dept { get; set; }
```

also you could  create a viewmodel

Comment: Both options suggested work. Creating a viewmodel that is essentially identical minus the object reference seems excessive but likely how I'll go since I'm doing a DB first approach and want to be able to re-scaffold for updates. It is still really weird that the behaviour is different between 3.1 and 6.